# How to Configure angular application to connect to remote server in production mode

Tags: angular, rest, api

I have an angular application which is hosted on a server 'abc-def.com' and the corresponding REST apis' which allows the user to authenticate and use this angular application are on 'cdf-aqb.com'.

Both angular application and my REST apis' are hosted on tomcat on different servers. How can i configure my angular application connect to the server application once both are hosted in production environment.

In my case ,i have created a angularapp.war which is a part of an installer . This war is deployed in tomcat in abc-def.com. Similarly the REST api's code is part of another installer which is deployed on another server on cdf-aqb.com. In this case i won't know beforehand how to use environment.prod.ts. Because the server application can be hosted anywhere.

Should i ask for an input for the server api's host name, before trying to connect to authenticate to the server?

Answer (score 2):

have you looked into configuring your environment.ts & environment.prod.ts files?

what I usually do is the following:

inside of `environment.ts` I put the local url

```
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  BASEURL: 'localhost:3000'
};
```

then in `environment.prod.ts I would have:

```
export const environment = {
  production: true,
  BASEURL: 'cdf-aqb.com'
};
```

you will have to update all of your services to include the BASEURL
it would look something like the following:

```
return this.http.post<TokenResponse>(`${environment.BASEURL}/api/auth/register`, body);
```

when you use ng build --prod angular will use `environment.prod.ts` 
hope this helps

useful articles:

https://angular.io/guide/build

https://blog.angulartraining.com/how-to-manage-different-environments-with-angular-cli-883c26e99d15

Comment: In my case ,i have  created a angularapp.war which is a part of an installer . This war is  deployed on any system inside tomcat. Similarly the REST api's code is part of another installer which is deployed on any server. In this case i won't know beforehand how to use  environment.prod.ts. Because the server application ca be hosted anywhere.

Comment: if you are not sure of the url name before building you might need to combine the two applications if possible so they run on the same url then inside of the `environment.prod.ts` you will want to use something like `BASEURL: window.location.origin`

Comment: i used this strategy earlier, in some other project and it worked fine. but here my use case is like having angular app and server side code on different hosts.